# How to use subquery in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, subquery

I know this question might be repeated ... But I have query like this, I have a field "Compute_CRM_State" in my table. And that field contains data like "approved,pending,cancelled" but now i want to fetch total count of approved or pending or cancelled. I tried it with sub query. I can able to get total count of approved or pending or cancelled but.. I got same records many times.

[image: result what I am getting from my query.]

query :

```
SELECT        (SELECT        COUNT(Compute_CRM_State) AS Expr1
                          FROM            CRM_Doctor_Request
                          WHERE        (CRM_State_Id = 1)) AS PENDING,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(Compute_CRM_State) AS Expr2
                               FROM            CRM_Doctor_Request AS CRM_Doctor_Request_3
                               WHERE        (CRM_State_Id = 2)) AS Approved,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(Compute_CRM_State) AS Expr3
                               FROM            CRM_Doctor_Request AS CRM_Doctor_Request_2
                               WHERE        (CRM_State_Id = 3)) AS CANCELLED
FROM            CRM_Doctor_Request AS CRM_Doctor_Request_1
```

There should be display only 1 record of count.. but it is getting display the number of times that number of records in table contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you were not getting the total count correctly and getting many records instead, is that the `COUNT`s are selected as a correlated subquery, so you will got the count for each record in the table.

To fix that you have to use the aggregate function in the outer query, not from the correlated subuery. And to get those total count for each status, use the `CASE` expression to do this like so:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN CRM_State_Id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PENDING,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CRM_State_Id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Approved,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CRM_State_Id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CANCELLED
FROM  CRM_Doctor_Request;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86e27/2)

---

**Or:** you can use the `PIVOT` table operator to do the same thing:

```
SELECT 
  [1] AS PENDING, 
  [2] AS Approved, 
  [3] AS Cancelled
FROM 
( 
   SELECT * FROM CRM_Doctor_Request
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Compute_CRM_State)
  FOR  CRM_State_Id IN([1], [2], [3])
) AS p;
```

[**Like this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86e27/8).